# How to replace multiple numbers placed consecutively in a string with how many were placed and the number itself

Tags: javascript

While the question title is quite confusing (please feel free to edit it), perhaps the explanation is better.

I'm looking a function that would take a string eg.

```js
"100,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,5,6,6,6,77,77,8,10"
```

and it would return something like:

```js
"100,2x255,6x0,3,2x5,3x6,2x77,8,10"
```

I thought of:

```js
str.replace(/[0-9]*\,/g, "Something, I guess.")
```

But being the noob I am in regular expressions, That was useless.

Comment: what have you done in order to try and solve the problem yourself? What code did you try? Where did you get stuck? This isn't a free write-my-code service - generally (unless it's very trivial or someone already has some code for the job), we won't solve the whole thing for you, instead we'll help you with a specific issue in code you've already written or started writing.

Comment: You'll probably need to split the string, then work through the array counting duplicates, and when you find a non-duplicate element (and at the end of the list) emit the last element and count into the output list. Which parts do you need help with?

Comment: Ok @ADyson, I'm going to post the other code I tried.

Comment: @Rup, Thought of that, tried `reduce` but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does RegExp work for you?

```js
const str = "100,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,5,5,6,6,6,77,77,8,10",
      
      result = str.replace(/(\d+)(,\1)+/g, (m, n) => 
                `${m.split(',').length}x${n}`)
      
console.log(result)
```